# reset of div's position only working sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue resetting a div's left position with jquery after an animation. I'm trying to animate a div from off the screen(left) to on the screen. However, I only want to trigger this animation if the value of scrollTop of the window is greater than a certain value. once the value of scrollTop is less than the value, I want the div's position to change so that it is offscreen again. This is working but only sometimes and I'm not sure why. I am also setting the position of the div to absolute at the same time I am setting it to go off the screen and this change always works!. Below is the code as well as the CSS of the div I'm trying to animate. Thank you!

**Function to change position on scroll**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if( $(this).scrollTop() > 500 {       
  $(".animated-logo").css({position:'fixed'});
  $(".animated-logo").animate({left: '20px'},500);
  } 
 else{
  $('.animated-logo').css({position: 'absolute',left:'-150px'}); 
  }
});
```

**CSS for the animated-logo element**

```
.animated-logo
{   
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left:-150px; 
  width:100px; 
  z-index:2;    
}
```

Comment: can you create a small snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, you have a syntax error.

I would approach this with using classes instead of doing it like this. At best you're going to have a buggy transition. You can adjust the css transition to make it your desired timing.

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if( $(this).scrollTop() > 500) {       
    $(".animated-logo").addClass('visible');
  } 
 else{
    $(".animated-logo").removeClass('visible');  
 }
});
```

CSS:

```
.animated-logo{   
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left:-150px; 
  width:100px; 
  z-index:2;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.animated-logo.visible{
  position:fixed;
  left:20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/783z9rhm/6/

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you say *This is working but only sometimes and I'm not sure why*, it's not sure what the problem is so I'll assume you are having issues with the animation after the first time it runs. The is maybe because you are firing it ON EVERY USER SCROLL ACTION, which is a lot. Using a flag to fire it only once every time the 500px threshold is crossed will get rid of the glitch

HIH

```js
var visible = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {

if( $(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
  if(!visible){
     visible = true;
     
     $(".animated-logo").css({position:'fixed'});
     $(".animated-logo").animate({left: '20px'},500);
  } 
}
 else{
 visible = false;
  
  $('.animated-logo').css({position: 'absolute',left:'-150px'}); 
  }
});
```

```css
.animated-logo
{   
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left:-150px; 
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  z-index:2;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animated-logo"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```